Converting from manifest V2 to V3 for chrome extension error
First off I am not a programmer. I am self taught and don't do it for a living. So I don't know a lot about chrome extensions but I still managed to create one that we use at my workplace. This is a chrome extension and the site that it is used for is only validated to run on chrome so using a different browser in not an option.
I converted my extension to manifest V3 about a year ago but there were a couple things that I couldn't figure out how to make work. The extension only runs on a few work computers so the parts I couldn't get to work in V3 were kept in a small extension in V2 that runs on the computer in developer mode. The problem is that I believe that soon V2 will stop working so I am trying to find a solution to get it to work in V3.
if (document.querySelector("[id^=GridViewTissueTeamSignatures_][id$=_TextBoxESigPassword]")) {
    // Select all elements with IDs starting with 'GridViewTissueTeamSignatures_' and ending with '_TextBoxESigPassword'
    document.querySelectorAll("[id^=GridViewTissueTeamSignatures_][id$=_TextBoxESigPassword]").forEach(function(element) {
        var num = element.id.split("_");
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ' <button id="simbutton_' + num[1] + '" class="header-button blue" style="display:none;">Save</button>';
        element.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', span);
    });

    // Add click event listeners to checkboxes
    document.querySelectorAll("[id^=GridViewTissueTeamSignatures_][id$=_CheckBoxESigSign]").forEach(function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var num = this.id.split("_");
            var simbutton = document.getElementById("simbutton_" + num[1]);
            if (this.checked) {
                simbutton.style.display = 'inline';
            } else {
                simbutton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });

    // Add click event listener for simbuttons
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.id && e.target.id.startsWith('simbutton')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //document.querySelector("#GridViewTissueTeamSignatures_ctl02_SignatureBlockTissueTeamMember_ctl00_CheckBoxESigInvalidate").click();
            document.querySelector("#FormLinkPanel_ButtonSave").click();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

when it gets to the line
document.querySelector("#FormLinkPanel_ButtonSave").click();
I get the following in my console:
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present
Here is the manifest. I wasn't 100% sure of what I was doing so I'm not sure if every thing in it is necessary. I am changing the site name in the upload because it is a private site and not allowed to give out the address.
{ 
   "name":"example.com Extension",
   "description":"Helps with the **** part of example.com.",
   "version":"3.0.8.6",
   "manifest_version":3,
   "icons":{ 
      "48":"icon48.png",
      "128":"icon128.png"
   },
   "permissions":[ 
      "https://example.com/*"
   ],
   "content_scripts":[ 
      { 
         "run_at":"document_end",
         "matches":[ 
            "https://example.com/*"
         ],
         "css":[ 
            "css/style.css",
        "css/jquery.multiselect.css"
         ],
         "js":[ 
        "js/dependencies/download.js",  
            "js/dependencies/pdf-lib.min.js",
            "js/dependencies/jquery.min.js",
            "js/dependencies/jquery-ui.min.js",
            "js/dependencies/simulate.js",
            "js/dependencies/JsBarcode.code128.min.js",
            "js/dependencies/DYMO.Label.Framework.2.0.2.js",
            "js/functions.js",
            "js/content.js",
            "js/main.js",
            "js/QAfunction.js",
        "js/addons/savebutton.js",
        "js/addons/hospitalNames.js",
            "js/addons/blood2.js",
        "js/addons/pdf-lib/trif.js",
            "js/addons/pdf-lib/versiti.js",
            "js/addons/pdf-lib/lnh.js",
        "js/addons/pdf-lib/VRL.js",
        "js/addons/pdf-lib/BBAcult.js",
            "js/addons/pdf-lib/Solvita.js",
            "js/addons/pdf-lib/BodyBag.js",
            "js/addons/pdf-lib/coroner.js",
        "js/addons/pdf-lib/chain.js",
            "js/addons/pdf-lib/property.js",
            "js/addons/pdf-lib/shipping.js",
        "js/addons/pdf-lib/VF.js",
        "js/addons/pdf-lib/Ossium.js",
        "js/addons/pdf-lib/OssiumCult.js"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "web_accessible_resources": [{
 "resources": ["images/*.gif","images/*.png","labels/*.label","pdf/*.pdf","html/*.html"],
 "matches": [ 
      "https://example.com/*"
      ],
 "extension_ids": []
}]
}


The line above it is a checkbox on the page and if I run that line instead it will click the checkbox. The code executes perfectly in V2.

It's a bug in ManifestV3 and the workaround is to add "world":"MAIN" to your content_scripts declaration or add a second content script with this world solely for the purpose of clicking the button.
